# Swipe Refresh layout

Tags: android

I have SwipeRefreshlayout.I have Implemented for recycler view.I have one problem I did not find solution from 3 days.Please help me for that,Thank you in advance for help me.Below is my activity of swiperefresh ,when I pull down list then swiperefresh progress bsr display but after applying

mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);

condition it still show progress please below see my code for that

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DashboardAdapter mAdapter;
    DashboardGetSet dashboardGetSet;
    ArrayList<DashboardGetSet> reportList;
    ImageView imgalertIcon;
    TextView txtAlertTitle, txtAlertmessage;
    Dialog dialog;
    Button btnCancel, btnExit;
    String alertFlag = "";
    String  user_id;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private static String LOG_TAG = "RecyclerViewActivity";
    int id;
    public static int totalCount;
    SQLiteDatabaseHelper db;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dmitdashboard);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        init();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()== true) {

            loadJSON();

        } else {

            showCustomDialog1();
        }

        mSwipeRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        mSwipeRefreshView.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(true);

                                        loadJSON();
                                    }
                                }
        );

    }

    private void init() {

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAdapter = new DashboardAdapter(reportList);
        db = new SQLiteDatabaseHelper(this);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshView.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.inProcess,
                R.color.colorAccent,
                R.color.roboto);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshView = new SwipeRefreshLayout(this);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new DashboardAdapter.MyClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                mSwipeRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        Log.v("Dashboard","SwipeRefresh ");
                        // Start showing the refresh animation
                        mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(true);
                        loadJSON();
                        Log.v("Dashboard","SwiperefreshLoadJson");
                    }
                });

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
                Intent intent =new Intent(Dashboard.this,CustomerDetails.class);
                int i = reportList.get(position).getId();
                intent.putExtra( "Value",i);
                Log.d("Dashboard","Value"+i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadJSON() {

        mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(true);
        pd.setTitle("Loading...Please wait!");
        pd.show();
        Cursor rs = db.getUserId();

        if(rs.getCount() > 0)
        {
            rs.moveToFirst();
            do{

                id = rs.getInt(rs.getColumnIndex("userid"));
            }while(rs.moveToNext());
        }
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Utils.url)
                .build();
        WebsiteService service = adapter.create(WebsiteService.class);
        service.getReports( id,new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                String output = "";
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));

                    output = reader.readLine();

                    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(output);

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
                    String reports="";

                    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("reports");

                        reportList = new ArrayList<DashboardGetSet>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            dashboardGetSet = new DashboardGetSet();
                                id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
                                Log.d("Login Dashboard", "Id" + id);
                                dashboardGetSet.setId(id);

                                String customer_name = jsonObj.getString("customer_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setCustomer_name(customer_name);

                                String father_name = jsonObj.getString("father_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setFather_name(father_name);

                                String mother_name = jsonObj.getString("mother_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setMother_name(mother_name);

                                String date_of_birth = jsonObj.getString("date_of_birth");
                                dashboardGetSet.setDate_of_birth(date_of_birth);

                                String gender = jsonObj.getString("gender");
                                dashboardGetSet.setGender(gender);

                                String mobile_no = jsonObj.getString("mobile_number");
                                dashboardGetSet.setMobile_no(mobile_no);

                                String zone = jsonObj.getString("zone");
                                dashboardGetSet.setZone(zone);

                                String address = jsonObj.getString("address");
                                dashboardGetSet.setAddress(address);

                                String zip = jsonObj.getString("zip");
                                dashboardGetSet.setZip(zip);

                                String city = jsonObj.getString("city");
                                dashboardGetSet.setCity(city);

                                String state = jsonObj.getString("state");
                                dashboardGetSet.setState(state);

                                String occuption = jsonObj.getString("occupation");
                                dashboardGetSet.setOccuption(occuption);

                                 user_id = jsonObj.getString("current_user_id");
                                dashboardGetSet.setUser_id(user_id);

                                String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                                dashboardGetSet.setStatus(status);
                                String report_status = jsonObj.getString("report_status");
                                dashboardGetSet.setReport_status(report_status);

                                String file_name = jsonObj.getString("file_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setFile_name(file_name);

                                String saved_file_name = jsonObj.getString("saved_file_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setSaved_file_name(saved_file_name);

                                String soft_copy_file_name = jsonObj.getString("soft_copy_file_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setSaved_file_name(soft_copy_file_name);

                                String soft_copy_saved_file_name = jsonObj.getString("soft_copy_saved_file_name");
                                dashboardGetSet.setSoft_copy_saved_file_name(soft_copy_saved_file_name);

                                String created_at = jsonObj.getString("created_at");
                                dashboardGetSet.setCreated_at(created_at);

                                String updated_at = jsonObj.getString("updated_at");
                                dashboardGetSet.setUpdated_at(updated_at);

                                String payment_type = jsonObj.getString("payment_type");
                                dashboardGetSet.setPayment_type(payment_type);

                                String amount = jsonObj.getString("amount");
                                dashboardGetSet.setAmount(amount);

                                String counsellor_id = jsonObj.getString("counsellor_id");
                                dashboardGetSet.setCounsellor_id("counsellor_id");

                            db.insertUserDetails(id,customer_name, father_name, mother_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_no, counsellor_id, zone, address, zip, city, state, occuption, user_id, status, report_status, created_at, updated_at, payment_type, amount);

                            reportList.add(dashboardGetSet);


                        }

                    mAdapter = new DashboardAdapter(getApplication(), reportList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    getCount();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getCount() {

        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Utils.url)
                .build();
        RestInterface service = adapter.create(RestInterface.class);
        service.getCounts(user_id, new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                String output = "";
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));

                    output = reader.readLine();

                    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(output);

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
                    String reports="";
                    int total = json.getInt("total");
                    Log.d("Login Dashboard", "total" + total);
                        dashboardGetSet = new DashboardGetSet();

                        dashboardGetSet.setCustomerCount(total);
                         totalCount = dashboardGetSet.getCustomerCount();
                    TextView mtotalCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countText);
                    mtotalCount.setText("Total Reports = "+totalCount);
                    Log.d("Dashboard","Total Counts"+totalCount);
                        pd.dismiss();
                    if(mSwipeRefreshView.isRefreshing()){
                        mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                mSwipeRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();



        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add(1,R.id.logout,1,"Logout");
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.logout);
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item,MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:

                alertFlag = "Logout";
                showCustomDialog();

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void showCustomDialog() {

        dialog = new Dialog(Dashboard.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        txtAlertTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtAlertmessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
        btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnExit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sessionManager.logoutUser();
                db.deleteUser( LogInActivity.id);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,
                            LogInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(alertFlag.equals("Logout"))
        {
            String uri = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_help";
            txtAlertTitle.setText("Logout");
            txtAlertmessage.setText("Do you want to Logout ?");
            btnExit.setText("Ok");
            btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
            btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,
                            LogInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }else if(alertFlag.equals("Back")){

            String uri = "@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info";

            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

            Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            imgalertIcon.setImageDrawable(res);
            txtAlertTitle.setText("Exit");
            txtAlertmessage.setText("Do you want to Exit ?");
            btnExit.setText("Ok");
            btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        }
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void showCustomDialog1() {

        dialog = new Dialog(Dashboard.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        txtAlertTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtAlertmessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
        btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnExit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        String uri = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_help";
        txtAlertTitle.setText("Setting");
        txtAlertmessage.setText("Network Not Available Do You Want To Go Network Setting  ?");
        btnExit.setText("OK");
        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
            case R.id.changePassword:
                Intent intent =new Intent(Dashboard.this,ChangePasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        loadJSON();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the line `mSwipeRefreshView = new SwipeRefreshLayout(this);` at the end of `init()` for? You have already initialized it by `findViewById()`!

Comment: You're welcome. glad to help :)